# Why does filtering return copy and slicing return view?

Tags: pandas

I'm exploring pandas and notice that filtering returns a copy and slicing returns a view.

Why is that so?

Comment: I think the question simplifies down to "Why does slicing return a view?", because there's no reasonable way to return a slice of non-contiguous filtered results.

Comment: Hi, here is an interesting read on that matter: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10954